# Microsoft Windows 10 shutdown issue

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade

Anyone seen this one yet? Just upgraded a few machines and this is what I get when I try to shut them down... Any ideas?

They were part of a domain before being changed.

[image: Shutdown 1]

[image: Shutdown 2]

Comment: Does the box disappear after the reboot?

Comment: No I am afraid not